# How should I show relationships between interface and class?

Tags: java, class, interface, repository, uml

I have Java Spring web application and UML. I have class `PersonalClient` (@Entity) and I have interface-repository that interacts with data base using that entity -  `PersonalClientRepository` (CRUD). For now, on my UML it looks like this (green arrow):

[image]

But I think, that this is wrong. Is there correct way to show this relationships?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You show an `«Interface» PersonalClientRepository` that extends `«Interface» CrudRepository`.  Extension in Java is specialization in UML. It should be represented with an arrow head that is a big white triangle.  (The small arrow on your diagram is confusing since it means in UML a navigable association, which is something completely different).

I understand that your `«Entity» PersonalClient` is the kind of object that `PersonalClientRepository` would find or store and that it is not itself an implementation of that interface:

You should then replace your green arrow and draw a dependency from   `PersonalClientRepository` to `PersonalClient` instead:  it's a dashed line with an open head arrow.  This means that the repository needs to know about the client (because it uses or creates some):

[image: ![enter image description here]

A class diagram is not a data flow diagram.  You do not use bidirectional arrows to show input/output.  For this behavioral kind of logic, you'd use an UML activity diagram.

The unidirectional dependency is sufficient to express that the repository deals with clients, regardless if it's input or output.
Conversely, `PersonalClient` does not structurally need the repository.  You could perfectly well use this client without a repository.

Comment: Isn't dependency dashed rather than dotted line? A minor detail though.

Comment: @Ister AH! Put this on my bad English vocabulary. In my native language, it's the same word for both.  A picture is worth a thousand words ;-)